# How to wrap the cell when writing CSV file using CSVWriter in OpenCSV in java?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm trying to convert the XML file to CSV.
Parsing the XML and converting is done. While writing to the CSV file I'm having issue. If the data is having the 'new line' (i.e., \n or \r), it is coming in the next record as new. Due to this I'm not able to produce the correct document using OpenCSV CSVWriter. I need to wrap the cell so that it can access/write the data into that cell.

```
CSVWriter(new FileWriterWithEncoding(csvFile,StandardCharsets.UTF_8,true),",",'\u0000',CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,"\n");
```

Above the CSVWriter I'm creating and writing the data as below:

```
public static boolean writeIntoCSVFile(CSVWriter writer, String[] cdrList) throws Exception {
        writer.writeNext(cdrList);
        writer.flush();
        return true;
    }
```

Input XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customers>
    <customer>
        <customers_email_address>abcd@gmail.com
        </customers_email_address>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <customers_email_address>efgh@gmail.com
        </customers_email_address>
    </customer>
</customer>
```

Expected output:

```
+++++++++++++++
abcd@gmail.com

+++++++++++++++
efgh@gmail.com

+++++++++++++++
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why OpenCsv is not writing the format you need, but [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/univocity_parsers_writing.html#writing) can do it. You could do this:

```
//configure the format as you want
CsvWriterSettings settings = new CsvWriterSettings();
settings.trimValues(false);
settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");

//create a CSV writer with the settings
CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(new File("/path/to/your.csv"), "UTF-8", settings);
```

Then update your method:

```
public static void writeIntoCSVFile(CsvWriter writer, String[] cdrList){
    writer.writeRow();
}
```

When you are done, call

```
writer.close();
```

Hope this helps

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)